# Firefox icon keeps going generic

Tags: gnome, icons

On my main Natty installation running Gnome3, the Firefox icon keeps turning to a generic icon. Yesterday, I fixed it by changing my icon theme from adwaita to unity-icon-theme, logging off, and logging back on. However, I had to reboot this morning, and the Firefox icon was back to generic, again. How can I fix the icon, permanently?

I have not had this problem on my Natty testing installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I worked around the problem by installing the Faenza icon theme and switching to it. I rebooted and the fix held. I have a real Firefox icon, now.

I still think one of the standard themes should have worked, though.